# Api's to compare text in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, string-comparison

I have a web-service in java, which is used by various services to insert data in mongodb. But since data is duplicate, we came with a solution to make a key-value pair of data and check it, if it is already present, before inserting in mongodb.
But comparing so many string is difficult task and it will take lot of time.

1. Do we have any lib/API's available for faster comparison.
2. Elastic search is for search, will it be good for text comparison too?

My String example

"Message:WSClient.FetchReservation::WS FetchReservation calledSystem.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) at BOTWSClient.ChannelDirectWS.YieldGain.fFetchReservation(String strReservationXML) at BOTWSClient.WSClient.FetchReservation(String RequestXML)"

Comment: Are the diffferent texts exactly the same, or slightly different ?

Comment: They are exactly same. Suppose from 1 million records, 50 thousand exactly same strings are repeated every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the text is exactly the same you could hash it and just compare hashes. If you don't have too many entries sha1 should suffice.

As [JonasCz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4428462/jonascz) said, please update you question so we know if the texts are exactly the same (my solution could work) or similar (my solution is not working).

Comment: I have updated my text. So it could be repeated my times.